# When and where java security set UserPrincipal?

Tags: java, security

in my project, I m using `request.getUserPrincipal()` to check whether user is logged in or not, but I am confused where to set the instance as logged in user?

and i also notice that `request.getUserPrincipal().getName()` return user login id .

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found where is the place we set our own db user details to the spring security Principal, we have a class which implemented spring security `AuthenticationProvider` interface , and inside `public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)` method, we set the value from `USER_TB` to Spring security `UserDetails` object. I am still investagating, spring security is a big part to learn